# Can I use a different font for elisp files?

Tags: fonts

My default font is Monaco. But I'd like to use Courier and with a larger size for `.el` files? How do I do that?

Comment: This has to be a duplicate question. Please search for how to change to a different font...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179942/changing-fonts-depending-on-the-major-mode

Comment: @Tobias @phils Thanks. I'll try these. So, instead of file extension `.el` I should go by the mode. So I'll set the font for Emacs-lisp mode, right?

Comment: Maybe, it is reasonable to use `prog-mode-hook`. That would include `emacs-lisp-mode`.